# How to validate if user has entered only two words in a string using Regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

```
string Name = "Fee ddd ddd ddd";
```

In the above string user entered 4 words so it is invalid

```
string Name="Dee eeD"
```

In the above string user entered 2 words so it is valid

How to validate it using RegEx

Iam using this code but its now working for me

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"[\w{1-2}]"))
     Console.WriteLine("valid");
else
     Console.WriteLine("not valid");
```

Comment: Try `@"^\w+\s\w+$"`.

Comment: Is this valid: `"Fee_ddd ddd-ddd"`?

Comment: What does the '+' indicate in the regular expression? Basically it indicates atleast one but here what does '+' indicates? Paulo Torrens

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to check that:

```
bool valid = value.Split().Count() <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If separator is *always* a white space, you can count it like;

```
int spaceCount = Name.Split(' ').Count() - 1;
if(spaceCount == 1)
   // Valid
```